# AccessViolationException on detectMultiScale

Tags: c++, opencv

I want use `CascadeClassifier` to detect a face, but when `face_cascade.detectMultiScale` execute in my code this is raised: `AccessViolationException`

This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FaceDetection.h"
using namespace cv;

FaceDetection::FaceDetection(void)
{
    face_cascade = CascadeClassifier();
    face_Cascade_Path = "D:\\book\\ComputerLessons\\CascadesFiles\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
    face_cascade.load(face_Cascade_Path);
}

Mat FaceDetection::detect(Mat input){
    Mat face = Mat(input);
    faceExist = false;
    if (!face_cascade.empty())
    {
        std::vector<Rect> faces;
        faces.resize(1);
        Mat grayInput;
        cvtColor( input, grayInput, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
        equalizeHist( grayInput, grayInput );
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale( grayInput, faces, 1.1, 2, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(100, 100));
        float maxArea = 0;
        int total = faces.size();
        if (total>0)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
            {
                Rect r = faces[i];
                if (r.area() > maxArea)
                {
                    faceExist = true;
                    faceBound = r;
                    maxArea = r.area();
                }
            }
            face = input(faceBound);
        }
    }
    return face;
}
Rect FaceDetection::getBound(){
    if (faceExist)
    {
        return faceBound;
    }
    else
    {
        return Rect();
    }
}
```

This is the exception details:

[image]

My PC is an x64 architecture and the image size is 800 x 600 and the [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) version I use is 3.1. Why did this exception occur?

Comment: This doesn't look like native C++, but rather like C++-cli (due to namespaces referenced in the exception information window). Please revise your tags. On the other hand, show us what `face_cascade.detectMultiScale` is doing, since the exception occurs there.

Comment: Not familiar with OpenCV. Why does `equalizeHist` is called with same parameters ? Looking at the documentation, second parameter needs to be an output array.

Comment: i comment --> faces.resize(1); but this time exception occurred this line : int total = faces.size();